# delete from linked/joined table in controller (express,nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express

how do i delete a record in a linked/joined table using nodejs express controller:

I cant seem to figure out how to delete a record from the joined table the propper way

This looks to cheap and i am sure it can be done in a better way:

Relations and my query so far:

```
db.team.belongsToMany(db.competition, {through: "competition_team",as: "competitions",foreignKey: "fk_team_id",});
db.competition.belongsToMany(db.team, {through: "competition_team",as: "teams",foreignKey: "fk_competition_id",});



 exports.deleteTeam = async (req, res) => {
  currentMonthEarnings = await  db.sequelize.query('DELETE FROM competition_team WHERE fk_competition_id = :fk_competition_id AND fk_team_id = :fk_team_id', {
    replacements: {fk_competition_id: req.body.fk_competition_id, fk_team_id:  req.body.fk_team_id}
  });
};
```

Here is how i add to the joined table

```
exports.addTeam = (req,res) => {  
  return Competition.findByPk(req.body.fk_competition_id)
    .then((competition) => {
      if (!competition) {
        console.log("competition not found!");
        return null;
      }
      return Team.findByPk(req.body.fk_team_id).then((team) => {
        if (!team) {
          console.log("team not found!");
          return null;
        }
        competition.addTeam(team)
          .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
              message:
                err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the stock."
            });
          });
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(">> Error while adding team to competition: ", err);
    });
};
```

and here is how i retrieve the teams:

```
exports.competitionteams = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  Competition.findByPk(id,{
    include: [
    {
      model: Team,
      as: "teams",
      attributes: ["id", "name"],
      through: {
        attributes: [],
      }
    },
  ]})
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Error retrieving Tutorial with id=" + id
      });
    });
};
```

edit:

relations:

```
db.team.belongsToMany(db.competition, {through: "competition_team",as: "competitions",foreignKey: "fk_team_id",});
db.competition.belongsToMany(db.team, {through: "competition_team",as: "teams",foreignKey: "fk_competition_id",});
```

Added models:

competition

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const competition = sequelize.define("competition", {
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    int_club: {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM,
      allowNull: false,
      values: ['club', 'international'],
      defaultValue: 'club'
    },
    gender: {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM,
      allowNull: false,
      values: ['men', 'women'],
      defaultValue: 'men'
    },
    template_path: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    logo_path: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    fk_sport_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    }
  });

  return competition;
};
```

team

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const team = sequelize.define("team", {
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    short: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    color: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    int_club: {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM,
      allowNull: false,
      values: ['club', 'international'],
      defaultValue: 'club'
    },
    gender: {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM,
      allowNull: false,
      values: ['men', 'women'],
      defaultValue: 'men'
    },
    venue: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    country: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    logo_path: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    fk_sport_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    }
  },
  {
      indexes: [
          {
              unique: true,
              fields: ['name', 'gender']
          }
      ]
  });
  return team;
};
```

Comment: Can you specify the relation betwen the two tables competition and team and also please confirm that you're using sequelize ?

Comment: You can check this documentation the method you are looking for is remove() https://sequelize.org/v4/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html